# Node.js on multiple domains using express.vhosts()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ip, vhosts

I'm back here with a nodejs problem, I am writing a node server that allows two or more app.js running on the same system using express.vhost(). But I'm quite lost now.

The webhost server is a dedicated server running Ubuntu and plesk and I've assigned 2 ip's for different domains.

xxx.xxx.xxx.123 IP is assigned to domain-one.com
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.456 is assigned to domain-two.com

both run a nodejs server app.js
and are each allocated in /var/www/vhosts/[domain-name]/node/app.js

The server running the vhost is at /var/www/node/server.js here is the code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app
.use(express.vhost('domain-one.com', require('/var/www/vhosts/domain-one.com/node/app.js').app))
.use(express.vhost('domain-two.com', require('/var/www/vhosts/domain-two.com/node/app.js').app))
.listen(3030);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world the server running ');
});
```

While in each app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes  = require('./routes');

var app = exports.app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world test file for [domain-name] running');
});

//port 3031 for domain-one.com
//port 3032 for domain-two.com
app.listen(3031);
```

then i run node server.js and every thing works fine without errors.

then i run a *netstat -anltp*

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19839/node      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19839/node      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3032            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19839/node
```

Ok everything goes as i expected (i suppose)  so i open my browser and type  *domain-one.com:3031* and in other tab domain-two.com:3032

but drops a Connection time-out in both domains... and when i run domain-one.com:3030 it displays the:

> hello world the server running

But not in domain-two.com:3030 it hangs also..

I, want to get my head around this and understand a bit about how my server and domains work and how to manage to run diferent nodejs apps for diferent ip/domains in my server...

somethimes the domain-two.com prints what the domain-one.com app.js file res.send() supposed to print on the other domain...

I guess im very confused now... hope you can help me out with this..

Thanks a lot

-ivan

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing anything else in your code? I just set up a basic app using your code and it worked fine. Are you entering the exact domain name when you connect to 3030? No extra `www.` or anything, right?

Comment: Yes.. and also if i run app.js from each domain separetly (node app.js) the domain-one.com:3031 hangs-up but if i go to domain-two.com:3031... it does load properly :S weird

Comment: Is the var/www/ directory the apache server? I'd be interested to see how you solved this because I'm trying the same thing. The way I see it, I need to map my IPs each to a unique port, and just have node servers listening at that port.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps better with this simple and precise syntax:
https://github.com/expressjs/vhost

```
//
// Module dependencies
//
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var app = express();


//
// vhosts
//
app
  .use(vhost('app1.io', require('./app1/app.js')))
  .use(vhost('app2.io', require('./app2/app.js')))
  .use(vhost('app3.io', require('./app3/app.js')))
  .listen(8080);
```